# Excel form object limit? Compile Error out of memory

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an excel sheet that opens a form but I seem to have hit an object limit of some kind. I say this because with no other code changes, if I add a few more text boxes it will no longer opens and I receive compile Error out of memory.

I have seen multiple posts about out of memory where the advice is given to use "set object = nothing". However I don't believe this will help in my case because I am not using ANY global objects and all my pvt sub variables are integer, byte, or currency. As I understand it, all private dimensions should be terminated by VBA garbage collector at the end of the function anyway.

I exported my form1 and it shows UserForm1.frx as 4,143KB and UserForm1.frm as 140KB.

Did I indeed hit some cap? How can I confirm that?
Is there a way to get more out of excel since this appears as a memory limit? 
If I am at a cap, does visual studio professional have a higher cap than excel for forms?

Comment: It is hard to think that such error is due to memory "hitting object limit", and it is also hard to figure out the problem without having more details. Either some bugs in the code that make memory grow without limit, or some bad installation in which case you might need to re-install Excel.

Comment: 140KB is a ***ton*** of code for one form module. How many lines of code is that? How many controls do you have on the form?

Comment: 3429 lines Not sure how to check controls, I don't think its the install, I only have problems when I add new objects. It of course could be an error in my programing but it does not seem to expand on its own. I just have a solid wall.

Comment: If you don't know how many controls you have, you have too many.  You might want to look into dynamic controls or sub-forms.  Regardless of whether that's the issue or not, refactor it.  That's what I'd call unmanageably large.  The actual VBA limits are likely similar to the `VB6 ones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240819(VS.60).aspx). IIR there's also a 64K limit on the size of the compiled binary, but can't verify it.

Comment: So size may actually be the limit here. With that in mind does visual studio professional allow for larger sizes? I would expect it would but looking at the link you provided it basically points out that size limitations can come in many different forms and its hard to track down the source. It is not really possible to reduce the number of object I am using and still create that I am building.

Answer (score 0):

By Default Excel is 32 bit and does have a low memory limit of 2 Gigabytes, however I found if you uninstall and reinstall as Excel 2016 64 bit you increase your virtual memory usage to up to 8-Terabytes. This makes any program less widely usable but it does allow for your to build greatly larger programs! That was the fix I needed any way.

Here is the source that led me there:
http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm

Comment: I also divided the form up into multiple forms and load them separately sharing date on the excel sheets